# After launch calendar intent, how to "go ahead" with the app? Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, calendar

**Escenario:**

I have done a activity that allows the user to set some info to create a entrance in the Calendar. Afeter verify all the info I launch the intent to open the Calendar with the info set.

Thats how is donde the button:

```
bnext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT).setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
                .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, beginTime.getTimeInMillis())
                .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime.getTimeInMillis())
                .putExtra(Events.TITLE, subject.getText().toString())
                .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location.getText().toString())
                .putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)
                .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "elias.ortiz@in2.es");
        startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
});
```

That opens the calendar. After that and confirm the entrance, the calendar app is still open (as is it normal) but when I press "back button" I go back to my app.

Image of the flow (Hand drawed)

[image]

**Question:**

After come back from calendar, is there any way to recognize that the entrance has been set, and go ahead to another activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `startActivity`, use `startActivityForResult` for your calendar.  Then override `onActivityResult`.  If the calendar activity returns `RESULT_CANCELED` that means the back button was pressed.  Call `startActivity` on the activity you want to display, and `finish()` on your current activity if you need to.